chromaDB collection.query WHERE
this is how i pass values to my where parameter:
results = collection.query(
    query_texts=user_info,
    n_results=10,
    where={"date":"20-04-2023"}

)
print(results['metadatas'], results['distances'])

what if i want my start day to be "20-04-2023" till today ?
I would like to pass range to this parameter

Store the date metadata as unix timestamp and employ the $gte and $lte operators to filter documents.
The reason for this conversion is because both operators operate only on numbers
Note that I opted to introduce a separate "date_epoch" metadata field for the converted date.
This makes it so that the year, month, day on the matching documents can still be read by a human.
import chromadb
from datetime import datetime

chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection(name="my_collection")


DATE_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y'
def to_unix_epoch(date_str):
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_str, DATE_FORMAT)
    return int(dt.timestamp())


collection.upsert(
    documents=[
        "This is a document about pineapple",
        "This is a document about oranges",
        "This is a document about mangoes"
    ],
    metadatas=[
        {"date": "20-04-2023", "date_epoch": to_unix_epoch("20-04-2023")},
        {"date": "19-04-2023", "date_epoch": to_unix_epoch("19-04-2023")},
        {"date": "21-04-2023", "date_epoch": to_unix_epoch("21-04-2023")},

    ],
    ids=["id1", "id2", "id3"]
)

results = collection.query(
    query_texts=["This is a document"],
    where={
        "$and": [
            {"date_epoch": {"$gte": to_unix_epoch("20-04-2023")}}, 
            {"date_epoch": {"$lte": to_unix_epoch("21-04-2023") }} 
        ]
    },
)

print(results)

For today, your query will be:
today = datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)

results = collection.query(
    # ...
    where={
        "$and": [
            {"date_epoch": {"$gte": to_unix_epoch("20-04-2023")}}, 
            {"date_epoch": {"$lte": to_unix_epoch(today) }} 
        ]
    }
    #...
)

